# Deploying PHP code in elasticbeanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS elastic beanstalk. I have been using this for a college project. I have deployed a working PHP code and its health is OK, but when I try using URL in my **environment**, it says:

```
forbidden error no.403
```

How should I deploy it?

I have already tried with many methods as seen in many AWS youtube channels, but without any luck.

Comment: can you please give more details?

Comment: in my college project i have to write a php code and deploy it in aws. while doing some research i found that elastic beanstalk can be used for deploying php codes easily in amazon web server. I have created an environment in elastic bean stalk for deploying a code. the code is running properly using Xampp. Now, I don't know how to go ahead and deploy it. when i tried clicking on the URL that comes with the elastic beanstalk environment BUT  it gives me a error saying forbidden 403. can you please help out in suggesting or finding the correct way of deploying it.